# Laravel 5 How to deal with database column names that have a space in them when trying to output in a view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5, MySQL.

I'm trying to get the data from my database to a table in my view.

I have done this before on the users table and listed all users from that database in a table on my html view.blade.

I can see by looking at both my user version and my new version that with in the blade tempting see below, there are spaces in the column names i.e. Cost Code need to be CostCode or Cost_Code:

```
<td>{{ $simstotals->Voice Numbers}}</td>
<td>{{ $simstotals->Cost Code }}</td>
<td>{{ $simstotals->Status }}</td>
```

To this, with out changing column names in database:

```
<td>{{ $simstotals->VoiceNumbers}}</td>
<td>{{ $simstotals->CostCode }}</td>
<td>{{ $simstotals->Status }}</td>
```

now I can't change the database column names so that nice easy solution is out the window.

So how do i get this to work, please help!!

Comment: To be quite honest, I don't think it is possible.  I think your only choice is to either change the column names to include '_' or just no spacer at all, OR pull the value using raw SQL and saving it into the collection you are sending to the view under the new variable name.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there anyway of giving the column names an alias within the controller?
i.e. - $simsTable->VoiceNumbers = 'Voice Number';

Comment: You can make a custom method in the model that will return the individual column needed.  That would probably be easier than the other thing I suggested.  So in the model you would add something like `public function getVoiceNumbers() {return $this->sometable->lists('Voice Numbers'); }` and call it using `$simstotals->getVoiceNumbers()`

Comment: Just to let you know Laracast came back to me and suggested I use 

$simstotals["Cost Code"] as i'm dealing with an array

also see: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-5-how-to-deal-with-database-column-names-that-have-a-space-in-them-when-trying-to-output-in-a-view

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed you were using a collection object... yes, if it is an array then that would work the same way.

Answer (score 4):

- ***Try SOLUTION below :***

> $eloquentObject->**{"Column Name"}**

Answer (score 3):

Simple, use the syntax below:

```
$object->{'Date Found'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Collection implements ArrayAccess, so it can be always referred as an array.

E.g. you can try doing the following:

`$simstotals['Voice Numbers']`;

Another "hacky" way is to implement custom `__get` and `__set` methods. In this case you'll be able to access these fields with something like `$simstotals->Voice__Numbers` (double underscore).

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class HackedModel extends Model
{
    public function __get($attr)
    {
        if (strpos($attr, '__') !== false) {
            $attr = str_replace('__', ' ', $attr);
        }

        return parent::__get($attr);
    }

    public function __set($attr, $value)
    {
        if (strpos($attr, '__') !== false) {
            $attr = str_replace('__', ' ', $attr);
        }

        parent::__set($attr, $value);
    }
}
```

Then extend this model.

Of course, this is a dirty "hack" and I don't think it's a good idea :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well, I rewrote the SQL query that was pulling the data to the array to rename the columns (this is mssql)

```
    $varName = DB::select(
                "SELECT [index]
          ,[Row]
          ,[Supplier]
          ,[Plant]
          ,[Buyer]
          ,[PO Created] as POCreated
          ,[Ord Typ] as OrdTyp
      FROM [dbo].[PullDaily] 
      WHERE XXXX = XXXX");
```